# Запятая в конструкции с ли...или

Tags: запятые, спп, или

Нужна ли запятая перед "или"?

***И совсем не важно, увидишь ли ты мою улыбку или увижу ли я твою.***

Ведь если союзами ли…или связаны соподчиненные придаточные части, то перед "или" ставится запятая.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***И совсем не важно, увидишь ли ты мою улыбку, или увижу  я твою.***

Запятая ставится, так как союз ЛИ...ИЛИ **в сложных предложениях** считается **повторяющимся.** Запятая не ставится, если соподчиненные предложения связаны **одиночными** союзами И, ИЛИ.

Примечание: **Частица ЛИ** во втором придаточном не пишется.

Розенталь http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=139#pp139

5. Союзы ли…или рассматриваются **как повторяющиеся**, а потому придаточные части сложноподчиненного предложения, связанные этими союзами, **разделяются запятой**: *И долго все присутствовавшие оставались в недоумении, не зная, действительно ли они видели эти необыкновенные глаза, или это была просто мечта… (Г.); …Налево всё небо над горизонтом было залито багровым заревом, и трудно было понять, был ли то где-нибудь пожар, или же собиралась всходить луна (Ч.); После этого решится, будет ли он воевать, летать, жить, или ему будут вечно уступать место в трамвае и провожать его сочувственными взглядами (Пол).*

Следовательно, запятая перед или не ставится, если ли…или соединяют однородные члены предложения, и ставится, **если они соединяют части предложения.**